# How to add a comment to owned JSON column in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, owned-types

Given an EF Core entity with an owned type that's stored in a JSON column like so

```cs
public class MyEntity
{
  public MyEntity( SomeMetadata metadata) : this()
  {
    Metadata = metadata;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Just for EntityFramework because it can't handle a constructor with owned type.
  /// </summary>
  private MyEntity()
  {
  }

  public Guid PrimaryId { get; private set; }

  public SomeMetadata Metadata { get; private set; }

  public class SomeMetadata
  {
    public string? SomeNestedThing { get; set; }
  }
}


public class MyEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder)
  {
    builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Metadata, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
    {
      ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
    });

    builder.Property(e => e.Metadata)
      .HasComment("Comment about this JSON column");
  }
}
```

The `HasComment` call will result in a failure when trying to create a migration using `dotnet ef migrations add`. The message given is

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Metadata' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'MyEntity' because it is configured as a navigation.

I understand that the reason for this is probably because if tomorrow I choose to store this `Metadata` in a separate table, then I can't have a "column comment" anymore. How can I go about overriding this and adding a comment?

The only thing I've come up with is editing the migration manually to add a comment, but this means that if we want to edit a comment later in the future, we'd have to manually edit it again, so I'd prefer to let EF Core generate the instruction for us.

Comment: I think the issue is that the SomeMetadata class is nested inside the MyEntity. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: @theCuriousOne I'll double-check if that's the case, thanks for the suggestion. It's nested for no particular reason other than semantics and me not liking to create another file just for this tiny class.

Comment: You don't have to create a new file for that tiny class, unless coding company guideline enforce it strictly ;) I am curious if the issue was resolve because of the nesting. Please add a comment as soon as you find out :)

Comment: I think you need a constructor to set the private properties or make your setters public. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#read-only-properties

Comment: @theCuriousOne moving the Metadata class declaration outside the parent entity didn't help, still the same message. Thanks for the suggestion, though, it was interesting to try.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I do have a public constructor that takes Metadata as an argument, but that one isn't used by EF, and in fact I had to create a constructor without `Metadata` purely because EF was complaining that it can't find a constructor that doesn't try to set navigation properties, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, everyone.

So far I still have no solution, and for now the code has been deployed with me manually editing the migration file and overriding the comment field on the column.

Answer (score 1):

`Metadata` is not a column in a table, it is a navigation property, which should point to a record in another table that holds your desired info.

However, in your scenario, you don't really need a navigation property. You can just adjust your code so that the "JSON" column is a string.

```
public MyEntity(SomeMetadata metadata) : this()
{
    Metadata = metadata.SomeNestedThing;
}

public string Metadata { get; private set; }
```

After these changes, `Metadata` will be an actual column in the table and your code for adding the comment will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't look good to me.
This would have me do JSON serialization/deserialization all the time (which invalidates the whole point of using `.ToJson`, I think). Or I'd have to create a new property on the parent class for every nested property in `Metadata`, which is what `Metadata` is trying to solve.

Comment: @Marian I think I misunderstood the description code, I see now that you were probably giving placeholder code for an object with many properties.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for not being more explicit about this in my question, my bad :)